# pandas complicated join operation

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I would like to implement a specific join operation with the following requirements:

I have a data frame in the following format, where the index is datetime and I have columns from 0 to N (9 in this example)

df1:

```
             0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2001-01-01   2  53  35  91  43  31   7  87  25  68
2001-01-02  12  97  86  59  51   7  75  25   6  40
2001-01-03  73  82  87   1  46  66  17  42  96  61
```

I also have another dataframe that contains the columns to be chosen for each datetime index, i.e. the values are 0 to N:

```
            0
2001-01-01  9
2001-01-02  5
2001-01-03  4
```

I would like to select the underlying values of the first dataframe, where

```
index df1 = index df2
columns df1 = value df2
```

For example the results for the above example should look like this:

```
join(df1,df2)=
            0
2001-01-01  68
2001-01-02  7
2001-01-03  46
```

Comment: So, could there be some date indices missing in df2 that could be part of df1 or vice versa? If so, what must be the desired behavior then? Could you post a sample case for such a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
print (df1.lookup(df1.index, df2.iloc[:,0]))
[68  7 46]

print (pd.DataFrame(df1.lookup(df1.index, df2.iloc[:,0]), index=df1.index))
             0
2001-01-01  68
2001-01-02   7
2001-01-03  46
```

Another solution with `squeeze`:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df1.lookup(df1.index, df2.squeeze()), index=df1.index))
             0
2001-01-01  68
2001-01-02   7
2001-01-03  46
```

Comment: I would think this would be faster, as it avoids any conversion to array. And good to see a NumPy alternative for pandas to do such fancy indexing.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines taken from NumPy's indexing methods -

```
vals = df1.values[np.arange(df1.shape[0]),df2[0].values]
df_out = pd.DataFrame(vals,index=df1.index)
```

Comment: @motam79 Also look into @ jezrael's solution as that might be faster.